# What's the name of this drop-out menu?

Tags: android, menu

i've seen this cool kind of menu in different apps, so i guess it is part of the android SDK. but i could not figure out its name. anyone already used it and knows how to create it?

[image: Drop-out menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We refer to it as the quick action bar, but it's not part of the SDK. The GreenDroid project provides an implementation of this component under Apache 2.0 license though.